# visual studio 2010 intellisense tooltip delay

Tags: visual-studio, tooltip, intellisense

Intellisense displays tooltip when going through list of methods. This tooltip displays with ~500ms delay. It's very annoying when I'm need to find certain method. Is there any way to make this tooltip to display immediately?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. In VS2008 intellisence was instant, however VS2010 appears to be fading it in. It's a short fade to be fair, but noticeable.

Answer (score -1):

My works fine. It could be cause by your graphic card, since VS2010 uses it to render controls (WPF). Change to better GPU

Comment: I have brand new laptop with Radeon HD 5870. Isn't this video card enough for instellisence tooltip?

Comment: What sys do you have? I have a bit old laptop with HD 36xx, and Win 7.
The problem what u have i notice on PCs with built-in video card. Check if any other apps use the resources of your PC.

Comment: Win 7 x64 I have. And I'm running only Visual Studio and Firefox now.

Comment: You cannot have a HD 5870 in a laptop, it is about the size of a brick.  Your hard drive is the more likely source of the slow down.

Comment: @Hans Passant it's mobile version of that video card. And I have Asus G73JH laptop, with 2 hard drivers with 7200RMP.

Comment: Indeed.  Sux when big iron like that performs poorly.